# Debian 12 no longer boots after sudo fallocate -l 32G /swapfile

Tags: debian, boot, swap

I use a dual boot laptop (Debian-12, Windows-10) with 16GB RAM.
Debian had no swap space (is that normal?) and I wanted to create it.

I read https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-debian-11

Without checking for available RAM executed
`sudo fallocate -l 32G /swapfile`

The command returned without error, but a Gnome notification appeared starting with "No space left on ...".
Believing that the impact of fallocate was restricted to the session, I rebooted.

Since then, booting into Debian freezes, booting into Debian recovery mode fails with "Cannot open access to console. The root access is locked". Only booting into Windows works.

I searched but found no advice.
What are my options?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You filled the free space in your `/` filesystem completely with a file called `swapfile`; no, files that you created do not disappear at a reboot, that would be bad :)

Nothing bad happened. Just grab a bootable image, (e.g. the debian installer), put it on a USB drive, boot from it, open the file manager, find the file and delete it; reboot.

> Debian had no swap space (is that normal?)

Don't know, usually some is created at installation time, but maybe not when you already have a generous amount of RAM? Not sure.

Comment: Thank you Marcus, I booted with the Debian installer and see the 32GiB /swapfile. I cannot delete from the Nautilus file manager, and I cannot cd from a terminal because /dev/nvme01p5 is a "block special".

Comment: You're trying to cd into the block device, you need to cd into the directory it's mounted on. The file explorer should show that directory.

Comment: The file explorer showed /dev in the front and /media under "property", into which I could cd and remove the swapfile! Debian boots fine again - you saved my night :-)

Comment: Regarding your comment on the missing swap file: 16 GB RAM unfortunately are not enough to compile Android AOSP from source. But I'll try creating a swap again to another day :-) :-)